# Does hash map implementation work somewhat similar as a graph adjencency list?

Tags: graph, hashmap

Hash map uses array for implementing bucket and inside bucket there is a linked list for holding the value inside the bucket.

Similarly for implementing graph adjencency list we need to create an array which will hold the value of vertex and linked list for joining the vertex with its neighbour .

Please answer for the same .

Answer (score 0):

Yes..  `adjacency list` is a general term with many *implementations*. One can use `HashMap` to represent the adjacency list. Another may use array of `List`s.. You choose whatever structure you are comfortable with. At the end, every vertex maps to a set of other vertices (its neighbors).